# best practice to recover or handle requests that is half completed or partially failed

Tags: coding-style, project-management, microservices, code-quality, node.js

Assume I have a request:

```js
app.post('/order', ()=>{
 // task 1
 // task 2
 // task 3
})
```

and `task1` and `task2` is completed but `task3` failed.
for example a user paid order successfully but saving order in database fails.

specially in node.js application that global environment is shared among all http clients and if app crashes, all other http request will be unfinished.
What are best practices to lower damages by such secnario?

Comment: As always, there is no global "best practice" - it depends on your specific requirements. You might want to roll back the completed tasks. Maybe you just reschedule `task3` to happen later. Maybe it depends on why `task3` failed.

Comment: Your edit makes this a wildly different question. One about request replay and persistence. Consider asking a new question.

Comment: @PhilipKendall I am aware of different situation and I made an edit to question for worst case (when an node js app crash). I know some operations can not be undo like an email reset token is sent but token is not generated due to error. but some operation can undo, like an order is registered but product number is not subtracted.

Comment: @candied_orange my edit shows a scenario that my problem arise. if I could not express my intension correctly ( lack of english skills) plz help to correct

Comment: @AliShefaee like I said, consider asking a new question. If you're asking about recovering queued requests lost because of a crash then this question and it's existing answers aren't going to help you. Changing it just made it unfocused.

Comment: @candied_orange thanks, your keywords ```recovering queued requests lost because of a crash``` helped me to google and get result for that

Comment: @AliShefaee sigh.

Answer (score 3):

Where a transaction is impossible you have to roll your own recovery.

This is impossible to do in the scope of a single request. But you can clean up after the fact if your audit log is good enough

```
Request
  log("start payment")
  Take Payment
  log("end payment")
  log("start save")
  Save order
  log("end save")
```

In the case you describe your log looks like

```
start payment
end payment
start order
error
```

A human can read the log, work out what happened and either refund the payment or retry saving the order. Or you write a separate program to go through the logs and do the same thing.

I've written it out crudely here to demonstrate the point, you can obviously have the same information without writing to the log every other line.

The key thing is that request process, just returned an error. There's no point trying to wrap a million try catches around it to deal with all possible errors, if the db gets unplugged it wont be fixed within the timeout of the request.

Having separate server side worker processes to handle things, rather than trying to do it all in one website makes you life much easier.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a transaction you roll back the work done by the completed tasks and report that the transaction failed.

Sometimes separate tasks must be successfully completed together or not at all. That's a transactional requirement. If task 1 is charge my credit card I'm going to be upset if task 2, ship me my widget, fails and you don't roll back task 1.

If that's the case you must have a means by which to roll back. Tasks that can be undone, a database that can be restored to a previous state, or a way to implement all tasks atomically.

A pattern you can follow here is called a [Unit of Work](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html). It prescribes keeping track of changes that need to be reverted if a roll back is required.

Doing this correctly, especially in a concurrent environment, is not simple. It goes beyond what I can fit in an answer here. But I believe you'll find the right terms to research in here.